# Можно ли настроить прозрачность fillRect в Java2D?

Tags: java, java2d

Можно ли настроить прозрачность fillRect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно:

```
Graphics2D g2d = ...;
AlphaComposite alphaComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5);
g2d.setComposite(alphaComposite);
g2d.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```